# How to make correct sortBy array in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have an array, which sorts the data by date added. I want to sort by price from high to low, now the information is displayed like this:

```
['name' => 'Simple1', 'price' => 0.20],
['name' => 'Simple2', 'price' => 0.25],
['name' => 'Simple3', 'price' => 0.10],
['name' => 'Simple4', 'price' => 0.23],
['name' => 'Simple5', 'price' => 0.35],
['name' => 'Simple6', 'price' => 0.28],
```

I need sort like this:

```
['name' => 'Simple5', 'price' => 0.35],
['name' => 'Simple6', 'price' => 0.28],
['name' => 'Simple2', 'price' => 0.25],
['name' => 'Simple4', 'price' => 0.23],
['name' => 'Simple1', 'price' => 0.20],
['name' => 'Simple3', 'price' => 0.10],
```

In laravel i try to make: `collect($items)->sortBy('price')->values()` but it't not help.

How i can sort by price from high to low?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-sortbydesc

Comment: it;s not work, received `Argument #2 ($flags) must be of type int, string given", exception: "TypeError"`, because how i say, i has not only prices, i also has `name`

Comment: What is `$flags`, and where are you using it?

Comment: i don't know what is it, in my function i don't use variable `$flags`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by @anyber. You can use Laravel collection helper [`sortByDesc`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-sortbydesc)

```php
$sorted = collect($items)->sortByDesc('price');

// To remove the key preservation, you can simply loop through and assign it to different array.
$final  = [];
foreach($sorted->values()->all() as $data){
  $final[] = $data;
}
// Now use $final to send back to frontend
```

Now if you want to go with pure php, still there are multiple options. One of them is `usort`.

```php
function sortDesc($item1, $item2)
{
    if ($item1['price'] == $item2['price']) return 0;
    return ($item1['price'] < $item2['price']) ? 1 : -1;
}

usort($items, 'sortDesc');
print_r($items);
```

Considering you scenario(data passed as json should be sorted but laravel collection helper preserve keys) I would suggest you to go with `usort`.

> Note: This function assigns new keys to the elements in array. It will remove any existing keys that may have been assigned, rather than just reordering the keys.

Comment: hm. i try first variant, it;s good in var_dump, but in vuejs site sort not changed :(

Comment: i work with axios post, to received data from laravel, and display in vuejs site

Comment: Can you add var_dump($sorted->values()->all()) to your question for better understanding.

Comment: your sort method works now good, var_dump sort how it;s need, but in vuejs site display old sort :(

Comment: One of the reason is numeric index of such arrays, which causes reordering while returning data as json. So if you add the var_dump after sorting, I can help.

Comment: it's too much code, i add it on pastebin: https://pastebin.com/u09GXcTk

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231533/discussion-between-dark-knight-and-yrbet).